# change vsftp port

Tags: linux, ftp, settings, port

I'm currently running an linux server, with the vsFTP (I used [this](http://secure-ubuntu-server.blogspot.com/2011/05/howto-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-server-1104.html), to set it up).

My provider blocks the ports 0 > 1000, I would love to remolty connect with it, so I want to change the port it listens to but I can't find how to change that.

I now connect with port 22 (sftp). And I would love to connect with port 2022 (the port isn't used on my IP). how and where should I change this?

this is my vsftpd.config: http://pastebin.com/TVX6fVR0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks good, are you sure you have restarted vsftpd and that the posted configuration is actually used?

EDIT:
Just saw a little typo in your config:

```
listen_port=2122
```

should be

```
listen_port=2022
```

Answer (score 1):

ftp_data_port = yourport

The port from which PORT style connections originate (as long as the poorly named connect_from_port_20 is enabled).
Default: 20

listen_port = yourport

If vsftpd is in standalone mode, this is the port it will listen on for incoming FTP connections.
Default: 21